# _heapwalk reports _HEAPBADNODE, causes breakpoint or loops endlessly

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management

I use _heapwalk to gather statistics about the Process' standard heap.

Under certain circumstances i observe unexpected behaviours like:

- _HEAPBADNODE is returned
- some breakpoint is triggered inside _heapwalk, telling me the heap might got corrupted
- access violation inside _heapWalk.

I saw different behaviours on different Computers. On one Windows XP 32 bit machine everything looked fine, whereas on two Windows XP 64 bit machines i saw the mentioned symptoms.

I saw this behaviour only if LowFragmentationHeap was enabled.

I played around a bit.
I walked the heap several times right one after another inside my program. First time doing nothing in between the subsequent calls to _heapWalk (everything fine). Then again, this time doing some stuff (for gathering statistics) in between two subsequent calls to _heapWalk. Depending upon what I did there, I sometimes got the described symptoms.

Here finally a question:

What exactly is safe and what is not safe to do in between two subsequent calls to _heapWalk during a complete heap walk run?

Naturally, i shall not manipulate the heap. Therefore i doublechecked that i don't call `new` and `delete`.
However, my observation is that function calls with some parameter passing causes my heap walk run to fail already. I subsequently added function calls and increasing number of parameters passed to these. My feeling was two function calls with two paramters being passed did not work anymore.

However I would like to know why.
Any ideas why this does *not* happen on some machines? 
Any ideas why this only happens if LowFragmentationHeap is enabled?

Sample Code finally:

> `#include <malloc.h>`
>
> void staticMethodB( int a, int b )
>   {
>   }
>
> void staticMethodA( int a, int b, int c)
>   {
>       staticMethodB( 3, 6);
>       return;
>   }
>
> ...
>
> _HEAPINFO hinfo;
>   hinfo._pentry = NULL;
>   while( ( heapstatus = _heapwalk( &hinfo ) ) == _HEAPOK )
>   {
>
> ```
> //doing nothing here works fine  
> //however if i call functions here with parameters, this causes
> //_HEAPBADNODE or something else  
> staticMethodA( 3,4,5);
> ```
>
> }
>   switch( heapstatus )
>   {
>    ...
>       case _HEAPBADNODE:
>           assert( false );
>           /*ERROR - bad node in heap */
>       break;
>   ...

Answer (score 1):

Use HeapWalk, not _heapwalk.

Try locking the heap during your heap enumeration with HeapLock and HeapUnlock.

It certainly sounds like your function calls are modifying the Heap and invalidating the enumeration. Some vague advice, perhaps you can create a new Heap specifically for any memory needed by these function calls. This might require significant reworking of these static functions, I know.

Comment: Hi Terry, thank you for your answer!
Following your suggestion, I played around using HeapWalk instead (i did the heap locking already actually).
It feels that HeapWalk works more robustly. I could not reproduce any of the above mentioned behaviors. I think I'll stick with HeapWalk() now. Still a strange feeling of not understanding how I corrupt the heap during _heapWalk() but not during HeapWalk(), where actually I do the same things as described in my original posting.
By the way, i am not aware of my static methods using any heap. I've got only stack variables there. Thanks anyways...